# While grouping in aggregation, use the most frequent value in array for duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I am using aggregation pipeline framework. This is simplified example. I am grouping docs by `name` property and pushing `city_code` values into array.

This is initial collection structure:

```
{
  "name":"foobar",
  "address":{
    "city":"foo",
    "destination_code":"FOO"
  }
},
{
  "name":"bazfoo",
  "address":{
    "city":"foo",
    "destination_code":"FOO"
  }
},
{
  "name": "barbaz"
  "address":{
    "city":"foo",
    "destination_code":"BAR"
  }
},
```

**I want to group them by `city` and use the most frequently used `destination_code` as single string value.**

and this is my query:

```
db.cities.aggregate([
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$address.city",
            "name": {
              "$first": "$address.city"
            },
            "city_code": {
              "$push": "$address.destination_code"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "name":1,
            "city_code": 1,
          }
        },
      ])
```

Doc from the result looks like this:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Ein Bokek", 
    "city_code" : [
        "TLV", 
        "JRS", 
        "JRS", 
        "JRS", 
        "JRS", 
        "JRS", 
        "JRS"
    ]
}
```

I understand that I should aggregate this further to get array of objects that have count of duplicates. It should look like this:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Ein Bokek", 
    "city_code" : [
        {"value": "TLV", "count":1}, 
        {"value": "JRS", "count":6},
    ]
}
```

and then sort by count (desc) to make it look like this:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Ein Bokek", 
    "city_code" : [
        {"value":"JRS", "count":6},
        {"value":"TLV", "count":1}, 

    ]
}
```

and finally take first object and turn it into string.

```
{ 
    "name" : "Ein Bokek", 
    "city_code" : "JRS"
}
```

Is there built in operator that would not require additional steps and could be used instead of `$push` on the first group in the pipeline?

Comment: What the initial structure of your documents, not your aggregation output look like?

Comment: @S.M.Styvane I added initial doc structure to the question.

Comment: Your pipeline should look like this: `[{"$group": { "_id": { "address": "$address", "dest": "$address.destination_code"}, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }}, { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }, { "$limit": 1 } ]`

Comment: I don't get it. What does it matter if it occurred "twice" or "six times"? It still a duplicate. So if you grouped all to an array and got `[ "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B"]`, then you just want to remove the duplicate "B" values only? So not really understanding why you would want to keep the others. If its just identifying **all** duplicates then do the `$group` as shown in the comment above and then `{ "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } }` instead of `$sort` and `$limit`.

Comment: @NeilLunn This is simplified example so it might not look clear at first. The reason I do this grouping is because I have large collection of hotel objects,  and some of them have incorrect `destination_code` property. Output from this aggregation is used as search collection for accessing data from the main collection. The reason why I want to group `destination_code` values is because the one that is most frequent is most likely to be the correct one. This is very shaky but this is the only thing I can do at the moment until data providers fix their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aggregation follows steps as described in question. Basically it groups by city name and then unwinds destination codes and groups them again.

```
db.filtered_hotel_data.aggregate([
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$address.city",
            "name": {
              "$first": "$address.city"
            },
            "city_code": {
              "$push": "$destination_code"
            },
            "hotel_count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "name":1,
            "city_code":1,
            "hotel_count":1,
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$city_code"
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "name": "$name",
              "city_code": "$city_code"
            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
            "hotel_count": {
              "$first": "$hotel_count"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.name",
            "city_code": {
              "$push": {
                "city_code": "$_id.city_code",
                "count":"$count"
              }
            },
            "hotel_count": {
              "$first": "$hotel_count"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$city_code"
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "city_code.count":-1
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "city_code": {
              "$push": "$city_code"
            },
            "hotel_count": {
              "$first": "$hotel_count"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "name":"$_id",
            "city_code": {
              "$arrayElemAt": ["$city_code", 0]
            },
            "hotel_count":"$hotel_count",
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "name":"$name",
            "city_code": "$city_code.city_code",
            "hotel_count": "$hotel_count"
          }
        }
      ])
```